# How to pre-fill text fields and click the submit button of a URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to open a URL, e.g. http://www.facebook.com. How do I open it from one page and set the values of the input field to my credentials and auto click the login button. I found the following code snippet:

```
<p>Your name:
<br /><input name="name" id="name" /></p>

<p>Your email:
<br /><input name="email" id="email" /></p>


<script>

var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the #
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
     document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
}
```

That produces this URL:
    `www.xyz.com/contact.html#name=some_text&email=more%20text&username=john&age=23`. (no credits taken).

But I am not sure where to enter the URL to hit.

Comment: Are you passing your credentials to a URL you do not trust?

Comment: for this you need to know URL first and then how  the form values are going that is  POST or GET request and based on this you can sent the request to server

Comment: Why did you tagged AngularJS in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the page and find the login field in the HTML.

For Facebook, use:

```
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "YourEmail";
document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "yourpass";
```

In the URL, try adding

```
<script>document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "YourEmailhere";
document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "yourpasshere";</script>
```

after Facebook.com

Comment: where to enter the url? i cant find any variable that has the url in it.!